# C# Cliente-Servidor envia datos como le apetece

Tags: c#, visual-studio

tengo un problema con mis aplicaciones cliente y servidor, tengo una aplicación servidor la cual envía datos a un cliente y este último los muestra en un form, el servidor que envía es el siguiente:

```
public bool Conectar(string iprasp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Conectando display...");
            conectando = true;
            string serial;
            //Always call UpdateDeviceList() before using AndroidController on devices to get the most updated list
            //android.UpdateDeviceList();
            //if (android.ConnectedDevices.Count > 0)
            //{
            //try
            /*{
                serial = android.ConnectedDevices[0];
                device = android.GetConnectedDevice(serial);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                conectando = false;
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Estadistica.registrarError(this.serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
                conectado = false;
                conectada(conectado);
                return false;
            }
            if (android.HasConnectedDevices)
            {*/
            AdbCommand adbCmd = Adb.FormAdbCommand("forward", "tcp:" + puerto1 + " tcp:" + puerto2);
            int resultado = Adb.ExecuteAdbCommandReturnExitCode(adbCmd);
            //if (resultado == 0)
            //{
            try
            {
                if (socket != null)
                {
                    socket.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                    //input.Close();
                    //output.Close();
                }
                //string ippc = "192.168.1.180";
                //socket = new TcpClient(ippc, puerto1);
                socket = new TcpClient(iprasp, puerto1);
                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    stream = socket.GetStream();
                    //stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                    input = new StreamReader(stream);
                    output = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    output.AutoFlush = true;
                    conectado = true;
                    conectada(conectado);
                    //output.WriteLine("OK");
                    MessageBox.Show("Display Conectado");
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Tablet conectar() socket no conectado");
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                conectando = false;
                Console.WriteLine("TabletCliente SocketException");
                //Estadistica.registrarError(serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                conectado = false;
                conectada(conectado);
                //Desconectar();
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                conectando = false;
                Console.WriteLine("TabletCliente FormatException");
                //Estadistica.registrarError(serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                conectado = false;
                conectada(conectado);
                //Desconectar();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                conectando = false;
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            //}
            //}
            //}
            conectando = false;
            return conectado;
        }
```

Este anterior es el método de conexión con el cliente, y para enviar datos lo hace con el siguiente método:

```
public void enviarTexto(string linea1, string linea2)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("enviarTexto()");
            if (socket != null && socket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    //output.Write(linea1);
                    output.Flush();
                    String result = linea2 + "\n";
                    String result2 = linea1 + "\n";
                    output.Flush();
                    //output.Write(result2);
                    output.Flush();
                    output.Write(result);
                    output.Flush();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TabletCliente IOException " + e.Message);
                    Estadistica.registrarError(serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    socket.Close();
                    input.Close();
                    output.Close();
                    conectado = false;
                    conectada(conectado);
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
                {
                    if (socket != null)
                        stream = socket.GetStream();
                    if (stream != null)
                        input = new StreamReader(stream);
                    if (stream != null)
                        output = new StreamWriter(stream);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

Y los datos se envian de la siguiente manera:

```
display.enviarTexto("Introduzca", ((float)cantidadACobrarInt / 100).ToString("0.00"));
                Thread.Sleep(4000); 

                String totalintroducido2 = Convert.ToString(totalIntroducidoFloat);
                display.enviarTexto("Introducido", ((float)totalIntroducidoInt / 100).ToString("0.00"));
                Thread.Sleep(4000);
                String devuelto = (((float)cantidadACobrarInt / 100) - totalIntroducidoFloat).ToString("0.00");
                display.enviarTexto("Devuelto", devuelto);
```

La cosa es la siguiente, yo en mi aplicación cliente la cual es asyncrona, al recibir datos por el stream los almacena en una arraylist, cuando este arraylist llega a count 3 lanza el método que los muestra en pantalla:

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;


        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            //Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);
            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();

            //Console.WriteLine(content);
            ListaV.Add(content);
            /*string valor = content;
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
            Form1 obj = new Form1();

            //obj.Show();
            obj.mostrarvaloraintroducir(valor);
            obj.Show();
            obj.Close();
            */
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaV.Count; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Dentro de la lista "+ListaV[i]);
            }
            string s = (string)ListaV[ListaV.Count - 1];
            //Console.WriteLine(s);

            if (ListaV.Count >= 3) {
                Form1 obj = new Form1();
                state.sb.Clear();

                obj.Show();
                obj.llamarArray(ListaV);
                obj.Show();
                obj.Close();
                ListaV.Clear();
            }


 public void llamarArray(ArrayList lista) {

            string lastvalue = (string)lista[lista.Count-1];
            //Console.WriteLine("ultimovalor"+lastvalue);
            string[] valores = lastvalue.Split("\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Console.WriteLine("1 " + valores[valores.Count() - 1]);
            cambio = valores[valores.Count() - 1];

            label2.Text = cambio;
            //labeldevuelto.Text = cambio;
            label2.Invalidate();
            label2.Update();


            label2.Invalidate();
            label2.Update();

            //MessageBox.Show(label2.Text);
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            Console.WriteLine("2 " + valores[valores.Count() - 2]);
            introducido = valores[valores.Count() - 2];
            label1.Text = introducido;
          //  labelentregado.Text = introducido;
            //MessageBox.Show(label1.Text);
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            Console.WriteLine("3 " + valores[valores.Count() - 3]);
            apagar = valores[valores.Count() - 3];
            label3.Text = apagar;
         //   labeltotal.Text = apagar;
            //MessageBox.Show(label3.Text);
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            //foreach (string item in valores) { Console.WriteLine("Valores a colocar" + item); };
        }
```

Mi duda viene relacionada con el método de comunicación del cliente servidor, este a veces me envia los datos todos juntos, los 3 datos, y a veces me los envia uno a uno o uno y dos y me descompensa el arraylist y todo mal por consiguiente, queria saber a que se debe este comportamiento y si hay posible solución.

Un saludo.